# How to count number of characters in a Java Array user input?

Tags: java, string, input, character

Help I want to know how many characters the user input in this program code.

This code would require the user to input 5 names and know how many characters the name is. I tried using for loop for the counter to output the characters used.

Is it possible to use methods for this code? I'm stumped. :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDec2_Baban{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int ctr=0;
        String arrayname [] = new String [5];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program will require you to input 5 names where each name will be counted and the length of each name will be displayed.");
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 names: ");

        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){
            arrayname [i] = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){
            System.out.println(arrayname[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayname.length; i++){
            char [] name =  arrayname[i].toCharArray();
            for(int j = 0,count = 0 ; j <= name.length; j++){
                if (Character.isLetter(name[j])) {
                    ctr++;
                }
                System.out.println(ctr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have something wrong in my condition or something. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that there's something wrong ?

Comment: I have errors running it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all the non letters characters from your string and then use length to return the number of letters in the string.

```
int[] count = new int[arrayname.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayname.length; i++){
     count[i] = arrayname[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").length();
}
//count[0] holds the size of the first name
//count[1] holds the size of the second name
//...
```

Comment: Not the one I'm finding though, need to see the total length of each name. But thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: @ScottBaban do you want to calculate the length of each name or the total of all names, and do you want to count only letters or all the characters

Comment: The letters of each name, I think I have to use the WhiteSpace method here or I'm wrong?

Comment: Wow thanks, I thought I needed to convert the string to char. Why do I have to confuse myself? Hahaha you really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Took your code and checked it in IntelliJ. Missing something simple as you guessed.

In the following line:  `for(int j = 0,count = 0 ; j <= name.length; j++){`

`name.length` can't be equal to `j`.
Once that is changed it won't throw out of bound exceptions, it ran fine after.

Comment: I'll try using IntelliJ, I'm using Notepad++ right now. Thanks tho. One question though, can I use the Character.IsLength as a method and return it to the main method?

Comment: Changed it to other values, still got errors running it and it prints 1 2 3 4 5 only.

Comment: I'm not sure on the method question, as I'm just starting out. I had the same issue and I just pasted your code into an IDE (printing 1 2 3 4 5). But making j < name.length solved it. Have you changed anything else since you posted it?

Comment: Yep changed, the print output and the < name.length just what you said. It prints the total of my user input but not every name.